# how to create scheduler application for mail in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

my question is, I have to send mail at specific time daily, is there any way to do this in asp.net ?
give me appropriate suggestions.
Note : i don't want to run windows application or windows scheduler.

code which i used in global.asax

```
 private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AddTask("Remoder", 5);
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }
    private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
    {
        OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
    }

    public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
    {
        // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
        // re-add our task so it recurs
        AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
    }
    public void Remoder()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Hello Start");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this technique from Jeff Himself is what you need:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: but i want to call specific function, it it possible ?

Comment: Yes, see the comment // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest - replace that with a function call. E.g `if(k == "callFunction"){ callFunction();}`

Comment: where i have to write if(k == "callFunction"){ callFunction();} ?

Comment: OK, so you have added "Remoder" as the task name, so in `CacheItemRemoved`, you can now add `if(k == "Remoder"){Remoder();}` before the existing `AddTask` line.

Comment: is there any problem occur in bandwidth or application crash with this code ?

Comment: I think the best answers to that question are in the comments of the article I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I tried the hack ... turning your application global.asax into a virtual scheduler.  It was my choice, because my server admin department simply refuses (because they don't understand) to do it with windows, or a database job.

If I had my druthers though, I'd use a database "job", since sql-server can send mail directly.  Not sure what db you're using, but if you have the necessary access, I'd recommend looking for a solution like that, instead of trying to fool your asp.net app.

Comment: because so hosting company not allows us to use windows job scheduler or sql job scheduler